# Java MySQL ?autoReconnect=true

Tags: java, mysql

I have this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 54,607,614 milliseconds ago.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 54,607,614 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. 
You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, 
increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

But I don't know what's the error in my Programm, I have `autoReconnect=true`... :

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", username, password
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is warning message, that no sql commands have been send over specified period to the Mysql server. JDBC can do auto reconnect on such event.

Add also parameter

```
cmaxReconnets=5
```

to try to reconnect 5 times before give up.
Also there is parameter for initial timeout before retry

```
initialTimeout=1
```

You can add those to properties when obtaining connection.

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, properties)
```

Comment: I have now this:

`connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?autoReconnect=true&cmaxReconnets=5&initialTimeout=1&useSSL=false", username, password
);`

Butt i becomes the error again... And I cant use `DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, properties)`
because i must add password and username... Idk did i have anything wrong?

Comment: Part from my code:

    public void setConnection()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer() ;
        sb.append("jdbc:mysql://" + getHostname() + ":" + getPort() + "/" + getDatabase() + "?user=" + getUsername() + "&password=" + getPassword());
        sb.append("&connectTimeout=" + getDefaultTimeout() * 1000);
        setConnectionString(sb.toString()) ;
        getProperties().put("autoReconnect", "true") ;
        getProperties().put("cmaxReconnets", "5") ;
        getProperties().put("initialTimeout", "1") ;
    }

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: Please, can you accept the answer if it fills your needs